# Opengl fragment shader only drawing in white

Tags: c++, opengl, colors, shader

My fragment shader is not working , it is only drawing in white.
I think the shader all together is not work.I tried changing the colorO multiple times and have had no luck.

```
#include <glew.h>
#include <glfw3.h>

GLuint compileshaders() {
GLuint vshader, fshader, program;

static const GLchar * vshadersource[] = {
    "#version 450 core                \n"
    " layout (location=0) in vec3 position;\n"
    " layout (location=1) in vec3 color;\n"
    "void main()                  \n"
    "{                                \n"
    "gl_Position = position;          \n"
    "}                                \n"
};

static const GLchar * fshadersource[] = {
    "#version 450 core                \n"
    "out vec4 colorO;                  \n"
    "void main()                  \n"
    "{                                \n"
    " colorO = vec4(1.0,1.0,0.0,1.0);  \n"
    "}                                \n"
};

vshader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
glShaderSource(vshader, 1, vshadersource, NULL);
glCompileShader(vshader);

fshader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
glShaderSource(fshader, 1, fshadersource, NULL);
glCompileShader(fshader);

program = glCreateProgram();
glAttachShader(program, vshader);
glAttachShader(program, fshader);
glLinkProgram(program);

glDeleteShader(vshader);
glDeleteShader(fshader);

return program;
}

int main(void)
{
GLFWwindow* window;
GLuint program;
GLuint vertex_array_object;
GLuint buffers[2];

if (!glfwInit())
    return -1;

window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Hello World", NULL, NULL);
if (!window)
{
    glfwTerminate();
    return -1;
}

glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

glewInit();

static const GLfloat positions[] =      {0.25,-0.25,0.5,0.25,0.25,0.5,-0.25,-0.25,0.5};
static const GLfloat colors[] = {1.0,0.0,1.0,1.0};

program = compileshaders();
glUseProgram(program);
glCreateVertexArrays(1, &vertex_array_object);
glCreateBuffers(2, &buffers[0]);
glNamedBufferStorage(buffers[0], sizeof(positions), positions, 0);
glVertexArrayVertexBuffer(vertex_array_object, 0, buffers[0], 0, sizeof(GLfloat) * 3);
glVertexArrayAttribFormat(vertex_array_object, 0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0);
glVertexArrayAttribBinding(vertex_array_object, 0, 0);
glEnableVertexArrayAttrib(vertex_array_object, 0);
glNamedBufferStorage(buffers[1], sizeof(colors), colors, 0);
glVertexArrayVertexBuffer(vertex_array_object, 1, buffers[1], 0, sizeof(GLfloat) * 3);
glVertexArrayAttribFormat(vertex_array_object, 1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0);
glVertexArrayAttribBinding(vertex_array_object, 1, 1);
glEnableVertexArrayAttrib(vertex_array_object, 1);
glBindVertexArray(vertex_array_object);


GLfloat clearcolor[4] = { 0.0,0.0,0.4,1.0 };
glPointSize(40);

while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
{
    glClearBufferfv(GL_COLOR, 0, clearcolor);

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    glfwPollEvents();
}

glDeleteVertexArrays(1,&vertex_array_object);
glDeleteProgram(program);

glfwTerminate();
return 0;
}
```

Can someone help me I am still trying to get the hang of opengl.

Comment: You could check for errors while compiling shaders. For example, you are assigning position which is vec3 to gl_Position which is vec4

Comment: Also there could be errors in your GL calls, you can detect those with glGetError(), or some glew error. Those are probable in your case since it seems like your screen is not even cleared

Comment: Thanks, the problem was setting gl_Position to position.Just a little mistake.Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies in your vertex shader, you can't directly assign `position` to `gl_Position` because `position` is a `vec3` and `gl_Position` is a `vec4`.
You can do this:

```
gl_Position = vec4(position, 1.0f);
```

or you can define `position` as a `vec4` even if your positions are `vec3`, the last component of `position` will be set to `1.0f` automatically in that case:

```
layout (location=0) in vec4 position;
```

You can detect compile errors after your `glCompileShader` calls, for that you need to call `glGetShaderiv` with `GL_COMPILE_STATUS` as second parameter, the third parameter is a pointer to the variable where the result should be stored. This gives `0`(`GL_FALSE` - there was some compile error) or `1`(`GL_TRUE` - compiled successfully). If there was some error, you can get the error log by calling `glGetShaderInfoLog`, you need to get the info log length with `glGetShaderiv` too(with `GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH` as second parameter). You can do the same for linker errors, but then you need to call the `glGetProgram*` variants instead of the `glGetShader*` variants.

Answer (score 0):

```
gl_Position = position;
```

Needs to be.

```
gl_Position = vec4(position,1.0);
```

because gl_Position is a vec4 and position is a vec3.
Thanks FamZ for helping me spot my error.